# Golang 1 in a million probability

Tags: go

I'm learning some Go and I'm doing some interview exercises. I have one exercice where one is asked to perform some operation randomly with a 1 in a million probability.

Let's say that I want to `return true` once in a million.

If my math is still right (and Google too), I would calculate this with the expression `math.Pow(1-(1/1000000),1000000)` however this keeps returning me `1` constantly, which doesn't seem correct.

Given this description, how could I ensure that I'd return `true` only once in a million? This sounds trivial but I'm really struggling with it.

Comment: You're using a constant mathematical calculation, if it *didn't* return the same value every time, that would be a HUGE problem - the same as if `1 + 1` didn't always evaluate to `2`. If you want a random probabilistic chance, you'll need to use an RNG, e.g. [`math/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go standard library has a `rand` package and it has `Intn()` function that will give you a pseudo-random number in the range of [0 , n). So to fire an event with probability of 1/1000000 you could do something like

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    n := rand.Intn(1000000)
    if n == 154397 {
        fmt.Println("I am a lucky bastard!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("I am not")
    }
}
```

Needless to say that 154397 could be replaced with any other integer in range. [Link to playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YIyIzeX4UP7)

Answer (score 3):

> the expression `math.Pow(1-(1/1000000),1000000)` however this keeps
>   returning me `1` constantly, which doesn't seem correct.

---

`1/1000000` is zero. Integer division truncates towards zero.

Use floating-point, 1.0 not 1:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    p := math.Pow(1-(1/1000000), 1000000)
    fmt.Println(p)
    p = math.Pow(1-(1.0/1000000), 1000000)
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ZhUAe6imaNv

Output:

```
1
0.36787925722078507
```

Comment: Ah there's my error.. I used `1/1000000` rather than `1.0/1000000`